# Trouble Loading Data from Azure Synapse Analytics Serverless SQL Endpoint into Power BI: How to Resolve?

Tags: azure, powerbi

I'm attempting to connect Azure Synapse Analytics Serverless SQL endpoint to Power BI, but encountering an error that I can't resolve.

Error message:

```
DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL: Cannot find the CREDENTIAL 'https://storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/container/folder/table1/', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
Could not use view or function 'dbo.table1' because of binding errors.
Details:
    DataSourceKind=SQL
    DataSourcePath=xx-ondemand.sql.azuresynapse.net;my_db
    Message=Cannot find the CREDENTIAL 'https://storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/container/folder/table1/', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
Could not use view or function 'dbo.table1 because of binding errors.
    ErrorCode=-2146232060
    Number=15151
    Class=16
    State=1
```

I've entered the serverless SQL endpoint, the database name, and the username and password. While I can see the names of my tables, I'm unable to preview or load the data inside them.

Has anyone encountered this problem before and knows how to solve it?

Thank you in advance.

#Azure
2. #SynapseAnalytics
3. #PowerBI
4. #ServerlessSQL
5. #DataIntegration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Cannot find the CREDENTIAL 'https://storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/container/folder/table1/', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
Could not use view or function 'dbo.table1' because of binding errors.
```

You have connected to the serverless database through a username and password. The database user doesn't have permission to read data from the ADLS account, which may be the reason for getting the above error while reading an external table created from ADLS Gen2 data. Instead of the database username and password, try connecting with Entra Id by selecting **Microsoft account** in Power Bi, signing in to your Azure account where you have created the Synapse workspace, and connecting it as shown below:

[image]

Then, you will be able to read the table successfully without any error as shown below:

[image]